# how to store the Session_ID value sent by the server into a local storage in angular 2

Tags: asp.net, angular

After a successful authentication i am getting in the Response Headers the **_SessionId**  value  ( **Set-Cookie** : ASP.NET_SessionId = 02jsm1y515st1at34tnym1uu; path=/; HttpOnly ) .

I need to store this value to send it back in any other request.

Is there any ideas.

Note: I'm using  CORS

## Global.asax

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e){
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin" , "*");
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

}
```

## Angular 2 service : Get method

```
 login(value: any) {


    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('module', 'login'); 
    params.set('user', (value.email).toString());
    params.set('pass', (value.password).toString());

    return this.http.get(this.loginUri, {  
        search: params  
    })
        .map(res => {
            console.log("===++" + res.text());
             console.log("=====" + res.text().replace(/([a-z][^:]*)(?=\s*:)/g, '"$1"'));


            return JSON.parse(res.text().replace(/([a-z][^:]*)(?=\s*:)/g, '"$1"'));

        })
    .catch(this.handleError)


}
```

[screenshot of the response headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzA1W.png)

Comment: Doesn't the response header saves it (in fact browser) itself to browser cookies?

Comment: i checked my cookie it's empty  @HoBi

Comment: Is Console log printing expected data?

Comment: solved this by adding withCredentiels: true to the get method             `return this.http.get(this.KeyUri, { search: params, withCredentials:true  }`